# Settings not working on Facebook, cannot log out

Tags: facebook, logout

I am trying to log out of Facebook, as usual, and when I click on the account drop down menu, I get a twirling grey circle and this: "The content you requested cannot be displayed  at the moment. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked  on may have expired or you may not have permission to view this page." This is happening on 3 browsers: Chrome, Firefox and Safari, so it is not a browser issue. How can I bypass this? Other FB navigation is working; just the account menu seems to be broken.

Comment: Having the same error messages with other actions in FB as well.... Just wait till they fix it.

Comment: I also get a lot of *This content is no longer available
The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.*

Comment: You could try clearing the cache and deleting cookies in your web browser. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Answer (score -2):

Open https://m.facebook.com/ in a new tab,
choose menu and scroll down and log off